# Jmeter : Increment count of user variable for n user(thread) and n request

Tags: jmeter, counter, increment

I have Jmeter test with following scenario:

```
Thread (5 in number)
  -> counter X (X value 0, increment by 1 till 10)
  -> req1 uses X
  -> req2 uses X
```

Now what I want to achieve is that, for each user and each request the value of X should increment without overlapping/repeating i.e If I run it for 5 user * 2 runs = 10 request, than value of X for each request should very from 1 to 10 without repetition.

But above approach does not work as the each user the counter start from 0 so I get duplicate X in request made, something like

```
user1 -> req1 X = 0, 
user1 -> req2 X = 1
user2 -> req1 X = 0
user2 -> req2 X = 1
```

I tried to use user defined variable with :
bean shell  pre-process still the same issue.
even the ${__intSum(${X},1,X)} does not solve the issue.
even tried ${__counter(TRUE,X)} does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

JMeter `Counter` by default does not give duplicate value - gets incremented automatically for each user & for each iteration.

Uncheck 'Track counter independently for each user' check box.

[image]

EDIT:

If your requirement is to increase the counter for each request inside a thread-group, It is not possible with counter. You can use JMeter properties to do that.

Check here - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html - Sharing Variables.

Comment: this too does not work  I tried it. kindly see this image :http://i.stack.imgur.com/C2RtN.png

Comment: sorry it does not solve my problem ..yes Jmeter Properties  can be used for sharing a variable across many threads. but the problem with this approach is that even the Jmeter Properties are not thread safe so if I ran test say with 5 or more threads  and each  thread tries to update the value of this variable in each request it made then you will land up with request having duplicate value of this variable.

Comment: What about writing a Java request which is thread safe, and returns the new value in a SampleResult? I'm new to JMeter, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is to use BeanShell preprocessor.
I used the bean shell with below value and use the variable "transactionId" in all my request and I get different value for each call by each thread(user).

```
import java.util.Random;

long x = 1000000L;
long y = 9999999L;
Random r = new Random();
long number = x+((long)(r.nextDouble()*(y-x)));

vars.put("transactionId",number );

log.info(" transactionId : " +  number );
```

Note : You can use any logic to generate the value as per your requirement.

Comment: is your requirement to get some unique random number?

Comment: No it was not . .it was to get sequential number in each  request. It seems even this solution does not work :( :(  same issue of thread safe occurred :(

Comment: As you went with random number generation, you can use counter/property  as usual & append ${__threadNum} to make it unique.